# Mysql multi column index not used with IN statement

Tags: mysql

mysql version 5.7.33

I have a mysql table of hierarchical folders like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `FoldersCopy` (
    `folderId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tenantId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `userId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `folderName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `folderIdParent` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderPathIds` VARCHAR(10000) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `trashItemId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderIsPublic` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `folderIsPublicUserId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderDtCreate` DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderDtUpdate` DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`folderId`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `IX_Path` (`folderPathIds`(3072)) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `IX_Parent` (`tenantId`, `folderIdParent`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `IX_PublicOrUserId` (`tenantId`, `folderIsPublicUserId`, `folderDtUpdate`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Due to user permissions, I need to query for all folders which are public or owned by user itself.

```
SELECT folderId FROM Folders
    WHERE tenantId = x
      AND (userId = <userId>
            OR folderIsPublic = 1)
```

Since it is not possible to optimize the full query (due to OR on different fields), I added the column folderIsPublicUserId = IF(folderIsPublic, 0, userId)

Now I can query like so:

```
SELECT folderId FROM Folders
    WHERE tenantId = x
      AND folderIsPublicUserId IN (0, <userId>)
ORDER BY folderDtUpdate DESC
```

IMHO mysql should be able to use index IX_PublicOrUserId, but does not.
EXPLAIN output:

```
"id": 1,
"select_type": "SIMPLE",
"table": "FoldersCopy",
"partitions": null,
"type": "ref",
"possible_keys": "IX_Parent,IX_PublicOrUserId",
"key": "IX_Parent",
"key_len": "8",
"ref": "const",
"rows": 1,
"filtered": 20.00,
"Extra": "Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort"
```

It could use the index (in possible_keys), but it doesn't. There are around 1000 folders in table, and 2 matches the query.

I tried using "FORCE INDEX(IX_PublicOrUserId)". Now the index is used, but there is still a filesort in OPTIMIZE output, so I guess the index is not really in use.

If I query like so, the index is being used:

```
SELECT folderId FROM Folders
    WHERE tenantId = x
      AND folderIsPublicUserId = <userId>
    ORDER BY folderDtUpdate DESC
```

Any ideas how I could solve that or why mysql does not use the index?

I don't want to use a UNION select with two indexes, as it has other disadvantages in sorting/filtering.

Comment: *Since it is not possible to optimize the full query* Who tells this to you? 2 separate subqueries and UNION or UNION ALL (depends on anti-condition presence in 2nd subquery).

Comment: As I wrote, I don't want to use UNION. I don't think UNION is an option when I need ORDER BY and LIMIT/OFFSET. Mysql would have to determine both results, and then sort in a temporary table.
In theory it could use the first two parts of the index for WHERE, and the third for ORDER BY.

Comment: Public folders supposedly have `user_id` column set to NULL - perhaps you can use `NULLIF(user_id,<userId>) IS NULL` ?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use a UNION select with two indexes, as it has other disadvantages in sorting/filtering.

Eh?  This should not 'hurt':

```
SELECT folderId FROM Folders
    WHERE tenantId = x
      AND userId = <userId>
UNION ALL
SELECT folderId FROM Folders
    WHERE tenantId = x
      AND folderIsPublic = 1
```

and add

```
INDEX(userId, tenantId, folderDtUpdate)
```

(If there could be dups that you don't want, change to `UNION DISTINCT`, which is a little slower.)

Your second query may benefit from this "covering" index that *may* avoid the sort:

```
INDEX(tenantId, folderDtUpdate, folderIsPublicUserId, folderId)
```

For the third query, my first index should help.

Answer (score 1):

After testing various combinations of indexes, a ANALYZE TABLE statement solved my index issue.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html

```
CREATE TABLE `Folders` (
    `folderId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tenantId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `userId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `folderName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `folderIdParent` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderPathIds` VARCHAR(10000) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `trashItemId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderIsPublic` TINYINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `folderIsPublicUserId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderDtCreate` DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `folderDtUpdate` DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`folderId`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `IX_Path` (`folderPathIds`(3072)) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `IX_Parent` (`tenantId`, `folderIdParent`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `IX_PublicOrUserId` (`tenantId`, `folderIsPublicUserId`, `folderDtUpdate`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I'm still using a column which combines userId and folderIsPublic:

```
folderIsPublicUserId = IF(folderIsPublic, 0, userId)
```

Both queries now use the IX_PublicOrUserId index:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM Folders
WHERE (tenantId, folderIsPublicUserId) IN ((2, 2), (2, 0))
ORDER BY folderDtUpdate
```

Output:

```
"id": 1,
"select_type": "SIMPLE",
"table": "Folders",
"partitions": null,
"type": "range",
"possible_keys": "IX_Parent,IX_PublicOrUserId",
"key": "IX_PublicOrUserId",
"key_len": "17",
"ref": null,
"rows": 26,
"filtered": 100.00,
"Extra": "Using where; Using filesort"
```

Original version:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM Folders
WHERE tenantId = 2 AND folderIsPublicUserId IN (2, 0)
ORDER BY folderDtUpdate
```

Output:

```
"id": 1,
"select_type": "SIMPLE",
"table": "Folders",
"partitions": null,
"type": "range",
"possible_keys": "IX_Parent,IX_PublicOrUserId",
"key": "IX_PublicOrUserId",
"key_len": "17",
"ref": null,
"rows": 26,
"filtered": 100.00,
"Extra": "Using index condition; Using filesort"
```

The ORDER BY still does not use the index, but I think I can live with that. At least the original problem is solved.